# Unable to get spring boot to automatically create database schema in gradle project

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have completed setup related to all DB in the `application.yml` file, but no DB creation message is visible in the log and DB table related error is generated when the actual api is called.

**application.yml**

```
server:
   port: 8080
spring:
   datasource:
      drive-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
      url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sys?serverTimezone=UTC&characterEncoding=UTF-8
      username: root
      password: ####
jpa:
   database: mysql
   database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
   general-ddl: true
   show-sql: true
   hibernate:
      format_sql: true
      ddl-auto: create
security:
   oauth:
      authorization:
         check-token-access: isAuthenticated()
   oauth2:
      jwt:
         signkey: 123@#$
```

**Application.java:**

```java
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@EntityScan(basePackages = {"com.springboard.backend"})  
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

**Users.java**

```java
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@ToString
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode(of = "uid")
public class Users implements UserDetails {


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(unique = true)
    private Integer id;

    @Column
    private String username;

    @Column
    private String phonenumber;

    @Column
    private String address;

    @Column
    private String address2;

    public boolean isAddress(String address) {
        return address == "우리집";
    }

    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="user_id")
    @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<UserRole> userRoles = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return this.userRoles.stream().map( role -> new  SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.toString())).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    @JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.WRITE_ONLY)
    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return this.username;
    }

    @JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.WRITE_ONLY)
    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.WRITE_ONLY)
    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.WRITE_ONLY)
    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.WRITE_ONLY)
    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return true;
    }

    @JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.WRITE_ONLY)
    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return this.phonenumber;
    }

}
```

**UserRole.java**

```java
@Data
@Entity
public class UserRole {

    public enum Role {
        ADMIN, USER
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Column
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Role rolename;

    public UserRole() {

    }

    public UserRole(Role rolename) {
        this.rolename = rolename;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your configuration doesn't seem to be correct. Ensure that `jpa` is under `spring`:

```
spring:
  jpa:
    database: mysql
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
    general-ddl: true
    show-sql: true
    hibernate:
      format_sql: true
      ddl-auto: create
```

Comment: I tried this but get error `Error executing DDL "alter table user_role drop foreign key FKj345gk1bovqvfame88rcx7yyx" via JDBC Statement`

Comment: And then could you see this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/60409986/11212074 ??